# Facebook linter says url invalid on AppEngine App

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, google-apps

I'm running an App Engine App which is being displayed on a naked domain using Google Apps. When I call the appengine url then the [Facebook url debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) gives the correct open graph values. 
However if I point it at the naked domain then it says the url is invalid and it "is blocked or is being accessed too frequently, so we're not fetching it."

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve it?

EDIT:

I've used the qualified (www) domain and redirected the naked domain to it. However Facebook still does not fetch the url giving the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine doesn't support serving off naked domains. You should use the qualified (www.foo.com) domain instead.

Comment: Hey Nick, since I posted this I found out that this is the case, I have used the qualified (www) domain and redirected the naked domain to it. However facebook still does not fetch the url... any ideas?